# Is there a log of BIDMC's bed capacity changes?

Tags: mimic-iii

I heard that one more MICU was added in 2008 (8 bed unit was added as MICU7). Is there a log of BIDMC's bed capacity changes somewhere, or at least a log of addition/deletion of ICUs? I guess I could infer some approximation of it from the data but if it already exists I'd be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on conversation with staff I believe that the hospital does keep a log of changes to resources such as bed capacity. These records are not available to the [Laboratory for Computational Physiology](http://lcp.mit.edu/) at this time, however, so the information that you are looking for has not been incorporated into the [MIMIC database](http://mimic.physionet.org/). If the records are made available to the laboratory in the future, then the situation may change.